# Coundn't install compression library to Xamarin PCL

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I try to install Microsoft.Bcl.Compression from Nuget, but I can't do this. 
I've got error Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Compression 3.9.85'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets `.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile158`, but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.
I've tried install other library from Nuget - System.IO.Compession, but I have had the same error.

How I can install one of that libraries. 
I need to compress my data before send to service.

Thanks.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: that library does not appear to support Xamarin

Comment: Maybe u can recommend me compression library for xamarin PCL?

Comment: You can try ModernHttpClient. It includes compression.